# Does R.java force all my layout elements to become public variables based on their IDs?

Tags: android, layout, element

I assumed that each layout's element id's such as buttons, textviews, edittexts, etc. were unique and private to that layout. This being said, you set the Activity to use a certain layout, you should only be able to find view id's based on the id's set in that specific layout.

However, I am finding now that I can reference whatever view id I want from my Activity regardless of the physical layout I have specified with "setContentView(R.layout.THELAYOUTIWANTTOTARGET)". Is this behavior normal, I figured only id's of those elements on the layout I specified above would be available? Looking at R.java, I believe all the id's I specified on all layouts are made public variables, thus, no id's can have the same name or unexpected behavior may occur!

The implications for this on my project is that I must now change all id's in all layouts to be unique. I figured my supplier layout > title textview would have been different from my customer layout > title textview, is this not the case?

Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. IDS are global, and for large projects it's sometimes a pain, leading to very long ID names. But that can also be used as an advantage, as you can reuse layouts on different activities.

For example, you can have a layout for a specific part of your activity (a custom buttons bar for example) that you may want to add to several activities. In this case, you can just inflate it into a specific ViewGroup of the first activity, and also in another ViewGroup in another activity. The methods to access specific buttons based on their ids can then be reused in both activities.

The method `findViewById` will only work on the activity you call it from. If a button (or any other component) exists on different activities, only the one in your current activity will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is normal. As far as I know, there is no way to change it.

So yes, the implication that you will have to have different names for views in different layouts is correct.

EDIT:

Actually... scratch that. I was under the impression that it was necessary, but according to

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

it isn't even necessary to have id's be unique in a single file. Just make sure you aren't searching in a tree that has multiple ids that are the same or you will always get the first occurrence.

It makes sense too since it doesn't really matter if the views have the same ID in R. I will keep this in mind going forward.

Comment: Somethings like this surprise the h*** out of me, like, REALLY? UGH! Time to start renaming!

I guess I have to do it manually in the XML files too as you can't refactor these can you like other items?

Comment: You can if you use IntelliJ ;) I don't know about Eclipse, I always use IntelliJ for my Android projects.

Comment: I just realized that what I said before was completely false. See edit

Comment: Thanks @Craigy, so I guess this means that if one layout has "my_button", and another layout also has "my_button", whatever the layout selected for the current Activity [by setting setContentView(R.layout.thelayoutchosen)], that layout's "my_button" will always be referred to?

Comment: Correct, since `findViewById` looks in the View hierarchy tree